# How to shorten multiple equality checks in logical OR?

Tags: objective-c, c

Is there a way in C/ObjectiveC

to shorten this?

```
if (a == b || a == c || a == d)
{

}
```

so that

i would have something like this?

```
if (a == (b || c || d))
{

}
```

I know the latter is not correct but what I want something that resembles plain english i.e.

If "a" equals this or this or this...then do something. I find repeating the == 
operator a bit redundant.

Comment: If the repetition bothers you, you can replace some of the comparisons with this: `a == b || !(a-c) || !(a^d)`.

Comment: 'plain english' is full of contradictions, dubious logic and redundancy.  Human brains can analyse text/speech by context, something that a compiler cannot.  Stop trying to make things worse for anyone debugging your code.  I would actually have used redundant brackets on your first example or, even more likely, used three temp boolean vars.  Writing 'clever' code is one reason why there are so many 'can't debug' questions on SO:(

Comment: @EOF not equivalent for all values of `a`, `b`,  `c` and `d` ;)

Comment: @ouah: It is, for unsigned integer-type `a` through `d`, and for signed integer and pointer-type, as long as the subtraction doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with objective-c objects:

```
if([@[b,c,d] containsObject:a])
```

Otherwise, there's no way to simplify your first implementation.

Answer (score 2):

No, you've written it correctly the first time.

Incidentally, shorter code is not necessarily better code. It's often harder to read.

Comment: Yeah, and so harder to debug:(